# Flow chart in beamer

Tags: beamer, flow-charts

I am trying to create the flow chart below in beamer slides, or anything close to it. Any help on this please! I couldn't find any similar chart here.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: Welcome. // 1. Simplify, to better get the message across. 2. Read, try and reread the tutorials in the pgfmanual. 3. Post again, this time with your compilable code (which is independent of beamer anyway).

Comment: For boxes with arrows se `arrow box` of `shapes.arrows` library ( `tikz ` documentatiom, pp 813)

Comment: Thank you all. I appreciate the advice from everyone. I apologize for my inexperience with creating charts in LaTeX; this is my first time using charts in latex. I assumed that there might be a similar chart template available somewhere.

Comment: Off-topic: Do the different shapes and colours have any meaning? Because usually they would e.g. diamond for choice, circle for decision or whatever. As it stands, you've got three different shapes, bars and at least nine or ten distinct colours, many only applied to a single shape. That's visually confusing, especially for a presentation.

Comment: @cfr, Thank you for your comment. The arrow-shaped boxes can be replaced with rectangular shapes featuring outward-pointing arrows. Additionally, the colors of these triangles could be the same. Colors of the ellipse shapes also could be the same.